# Service name and docker stack

Tags: docker, service, stack

I am creating a db service with a compose file (where the service is called 'db') and using docker stack. My db service name therefore becomes: stackname_db.
Is there a way to ensure that the service name remains 'db' (and not 'stackname_db) as it is called by other services in other stacks?
Thanks - C

Comment: There are few settings that you can tweak to get what you want. Check -p or the <COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME> environment variable. Also you can assign a <hostname> for the service you are bringing up and it will be accessible from any other service.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to **connect the "other services" to the same docker network** your stack is connected. From the other services, you can then call `db` (service name) to connect to reach the db service.

For this connection, you can either create another network, or *connect the other services to the service's default network*:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  other:
    image: busybox
    networks: 
      - db

networks:
  db
    external:
      name: stackname_default
```

Comment: Thanks - that made it.

Comment: Great @Christian68! Please mark answer as solution then, thanks.